# How to load XML "row" into index of listbox C#

Tags: c#, xml, listbox, indexing

I'm trying to load a single "row" of xml to a listbox index.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--User | 4/16/2013 @ 10:05 PM-->
<ContactBook>
<Contact>
<Name>
   <Name>personName</Name>
</Name>
<City>
   <City>testCity</City>
</City>
<State>
   <State>testState</State>
</State>
<Phone>
   <Phone>testPhone</Phone>
</Phone>
</Contact>
</ContactBook>
```

So I would like to make name, city, state, and phone show up on one line in a listbox, then have the next contact appear in the next listbox row.

I would also like to know if anyone has some good sites that show tutorials on how to update XML files, rather than overwrite them.

/*EDIT due to question in a comment*/

I didn't really know where to start. My xml file is written from a dialog (a few textboxes in a class) and the this.Tag updates the listbox, and saves to the xml file. However, if a second set of contact info is saved, it overwrites the first one, rather than appending it.

/*EDIT*/

Thanks to LexeRoy, I've gained a bit more understanding, however, I'm still hung up.

```
private void updateXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(book);
    var listBoxItems = xDoc.Elements("Contact");
    listBox1.Items.Add(listBoxItems);
}
```

where book is a variable representing my path to the xml file and listBox1 is obvious. 
Unfortunately, on button click, the first row gets this value:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d_11
```

Now that the datasource has been declared, I get a thrown exception:
[image: error]

Comment: What have you tried? There are plenty of ways to tackle this; you could try deserializing or linq to xml for instance. The idea is to turn this "record" into an object you can bind your listbox to.

Comment: that would be the issue. I didn't really know where to start. My xml file is written from a dialog (a few textboxes in a class) and the this.Tag updates the listbox, and saves to the xml file. However, if a second set of contact info is saved, it overwrites the first one, rather than appending it.

Comment: I have an idea but when I saw `then have the next contact appear in the next listbox row.` but then `However, if a second set of **contact info** is saved, it overwrites the first one, rather than appending it.`-- I'm stuck right here, is _contact info_ for `<Contact />` or by _second set_ you mean an update to the same record?. I think it would also help clarify if you posted the code you're describing in your edit, which creates the xml in the first place.

Comment: Try `.ToList ()` or find a way to turn this "XelementCollection" into an enumerable that supports it. You're getting this exception because whatever type `var` resolves to, doesn't implement `IList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345449.aspx) where you can represent your XML document and iterate each of its items. For your example,

You can create an object for a `Contact` where you will have a `Name`, `City`, `State`, and `Phone` properties.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("ContactBook.xml");
var listBoxItems = xDoc.Elements("Contact"); //This will be a list of IEnumerable<XElement> child elements of Contact xml tag
```

Then you can manipulate those things via your code.

**EDIT:**

```
listBox1.DataSource = listBoxItems.ToList();
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: Is there a specific using statement for XDocument? I have System.IO; and System.Xml;

Comment: Yes. If you check my attached link above from `XDocument`. You need to add its namespace `System.Xml.Linq`.

Comment: System.Xml.Linq.XContainer+<GetElements>d_11
that's what I get when I type:
    listbox1.Items.Add(listBoxItems);

Comment: Instead of `Items.Add()` Method, you can just set its `DataSource` value. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, and I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: see my update on my answer. We can use `.ToList()` extension method to convert `IEnumerable` to a `List` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I load XML:

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Lang.xml"));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Well, the thing is, I'm trying to make each row of the listbox gain a value of a string made up of each cell, so no, sorry. This didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to display the "members" (and their values I guess) of some "Contact" object in a listbox, one approach could be to create  a class for the "Contact" object and another for its "members":

```
class Contact
{
    public IList<ObjectMember> Members { get; set; }
}

class ObjectMember
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get;set; }
}
```

These classes can probably help handling the fields in the dialog, too.

Then as you read the xml you instantiate a new `ObjectMember` which you `Add` to your list of members (or whatever works out to give you that!). Linq to Xml is probably the simplest and most enjoyable way to go.

When you have all *members*, you can bind your `ListBox` to the contact's `Members` list, but the implementation of that depends on whether you're in the WinForms or in the WPF realm.

Comment: I have a class set up that instantiates the object member. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier method to bind by using Dictionary object

```
var dic = (from order in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   select new
                   {
                       UserView = order.Field<String>("Value"),
                       DevView = order.Field<String>("id")

                   }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(k => k.DevView, v => v.UserView);
                    ListBox1.DataSource = dic;
                    ListBox1.DataTextField = "Value";
                    ListBox1.DataValueField = "key";
                    ListBox1.DataBind();
```

[Reference Link](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/02/how-to-bind-data-from-xml-file.html)