# how to get xml data to listbox

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

ive got a problem with getting my data from a xml file to an listbox.

this is the data i want to get in my listbox:

```
<gjester>
  <gjest>
    <id>test</id>
     <fornanv>test</fornanv>
     <etternavn>test</etternavn>
     <adresse>test</adresse>
     <telefonnr>test</telefonnr>
  </gjest>
</gjester>
```

and i created a listbox in my gui. But i don't know what to write in my code.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
 I don't know what to write here
}
```

Comment: It would be much better if you come up with your trial, but look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050422/how-to-load-xml-row-into-index-of-listbox-c-sharp which is almost similar to your Q.

Answer (score 0):

This is .NET 4.0 (VS2010 C#) and is completely untested but may give you a start....

```
private void FillListBoxWithThingsIWantToSelect()
{
       XDocument ListBoxOptions = XDocument.Load(Filename);
        foreach (XElement element in ListBoxOptions.Root.Elements())
        {  
        if (element.Name.LocalName.Contains("gjester"))
            {
            foreach (XElement subelement in element.Elements())
               {
               if (subelement.Name.LocalName.Contains("gjest"))
                   {
                   // What do you want to add? The Attribute? Element value
                    listbox1.Items.Add(element.Value.ToString());
                   } 
               }   
            }
        }
}
```

Would help if you listed your platform and what you want in the listbox. 
You want to call this from your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are approximately a bazillion ways to add items from an XML file to your listbox but a good place to start would be the MSDN documentation for the XMLTextReader class and the ListBox.Items.Add() method.

Also - you will probably want to do this somewhere other than the SelectedIndexChanged event on the listbox.  For learning purposes, try it on a button click.

Good luck - and after looking into the above I'm sure someone will help you if you haven't figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

Can use dictionary object to bind the data from XML to Listbox.

```
var dic = (from order in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   select new
                   {
                       UserView = order.Field<String>("Value"),
                       DevView = order.Field<String>("id")

                   }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(k => k.DevView, v => v.UserView);
```

Click [here for reference](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/02/how-to-bind-data-from-xml-file.html)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: it matters, when you like to bind the data, hope its the exact answer.. cant write every line of code to express your answer, can only navigate the ideas

Comment: [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.